# HTML/CSS: Is it possible to have the z-index of an element in the foreground and scroll-behaviour and controls in the background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I know this might be a weird question, but I have a three.js globe in a div of a website. I want it visually in the foreground on top of all underlying elements. But when scrolling over the website, as soon as the cursor hovers the globe it zooms in and such suddenly you control the globe.

Is it possible to push the controls to the back, behind the background with a z-index and separate the visuals and controls?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're describing - it sounds like some kind of parallax effect?